# Passing value of query string in multiple views MVC3

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-3

I am successfully redirecting user after Login to a page called CustomerStart. After that query string (url) looks fine with the ssn like this

```
localhost:1234/CustomerStart?ssn=850406-0297
```

I am doing this by writing this

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "CustomerStart", new {ssn = model.ssn});
```

But when I click a button which has been defined in the _layout like this,

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("CustomerStart","Index", "CustomerStart")</li>
```

my query string gets empty.

I want to keep my customer to be in the same CustomerStart page both after login or if they click the CustomerStart button.

I also want to send my customer in different views when they click any of the button under the above mentioned one.

like this,

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("CustomerStart","Index", "CustomerStart")</li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bill","Index", "Bill")</li>
```

So, i need to grab the value from the query string always. But I dont know how?

I am new in MVC3 and I am totally lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("CustomerStart","Index", "CustomerStart",
                    new { ssn=Request.QueryString["ssn"]},
                    null)
</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Bill","Index", "Bill",
                     new { ssn=Request.QueryString["ssn"]},
                     null)
</li>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. i already tried that one. two problems come in after this. Compiler says that it cannot Resolve the action "Index" and in the url looks like http://localhost:1234/CustomerStart?Length=13 And thats why it looses the customer information i am retrieving in the view

Comment: works when i click fist time but then if i click another button and come to click it again its lost:(

Comment: make sure that when you come back after clicking the other button there is still value in the query string?

Comment: then you should pass on the query string value with the other button too... see the edited answer

Comment: Nope! it doesnt work. It tries to search for the following page when I click the Bill button. ~/Views/LoanApplication/123456-7890.cshtml But i want catch the ssn in the index page of Bill